# java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, compojure, clojure-java-interop

I am trying to add some data into app engine datastore. This is my function

```
(defn createUser [email phone roleId status]
  (println (db/isIdExist "users" "email" email))
  (if (db/isIdExist "users" "email" email) 
    (str "false")
    ((db/addUser email phone roleId status) (str "true"))))
```

Here I want to print false in body according to the value of `isIdExist` function (which returns true if email already exists else false) now when I run this, If `isIdExist == true` then it prints false but when `isIdExist == false` it adds the value in datastore but gives this error. Can someone please help why it is happening and what concept of clojure am I missing here? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume `db/addUser` returns a string in which case you're trying to invoke the return value as a function. It looks like you want to perform the insert then return "true" so you can use `do` to sequence the two:

```
(if (db/isIdExist "users" "email" email) 
  "false"
  (do
    (db/addUser email phone roleId status) 
    "true"))))
```

Answer (score 4):

In Clojure `)))))))` is totally normal and you see it everywhere, no cause for concern.

On the other hand `((` should stand out and catch your eye. It very often means:

- someone is returning a function.
- that function should be immediately run.

This pattern is not wrong in any way, just learning to spot it is a useful way to get used to reading Clojure code quickly. In this case it likely means there are too many opening `(`s in

```
((db/addUser email phone roleId status) (str "true"))))
```