# Is there a way to create a string in a function from a list in another function in Clojure?

Tags: string, list, clojure, char

Im pretty new to Clojure and functional programming, im trying to use two functions to concatenate some chars intro a string. My idea is basically like this:

```
(defn receive [char-from-list]
  (str char-from-list))

(defn send-char [list-char]
  (if (empty? list-char)
    (receive nil)
    ((receive (first list-char))(send-char (rest list-char)))))
```

So the idea is that I start with the function send and as a parameter write a list of chars like this:

```
(send-char '(\h \e \l \l \o))
```

The receive function with get sent one char at a time and using str it will add them all together and my final output would be: "hello".

When I try to run the code this error appears:
**Execution error (ClassCastException) at automata.core/send-char (core.clj:44).
class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.IFn (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; clojure.lang.IFn is in unnamed module of loader 'app')**

Im not sure if there a way to do this or another method but I don't know how, please help. Thanks

Comment: Im not sure if concatenate is the correct word (english is not my first language) but for this problem I have to solve, It needs to be two functions, one that has the list of chars and one that joins them together. I don't know if its because of the immutability or something like that but im not sure what im doing wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40753490/java-lang-string-cannot-be-cast-to-clojure-lang-ifn)

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you have 2 left parentheses in a row here:

```
((receive ...
```

Remember, in Clojure a left paren means "function call", and a string is not a function (function `receive` returns a string).

If you have 2 things you want to group in Clojure, you need to use a `do` form like:

```
(defn send-char [chars]
  (if (empty? chars)
    (receive nil)
    (do
      (receive (first chars))
      (send-char (rest chars)))))
```

---

Having identified the source of the error, your original question still is very vague and undefined.  Here are 3 ways of joining a sequence of characters into a string:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.string :as str]))

(dotest
  (let-spy [chars (vec "hello")
            s0 (apply str chars)
            s1 (str/join chars)
            s2 (reduce str "" chars)
            ]
    (is= chars [\h \e \l \l \o])
    (is= s0 "hello")
    (is= s1 "hello")
    (is= s2 "hello")
    ))
```

The above is based on [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).  Be sure to also study the [list of documentation sources](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation).